pseudo-periodic time series with stochastic period and amplitude
Pardon the less-than-accurate terminology (signal processing is not my field), but I have a time series that shows a pretty clear oscillating pattern between minima and maxima, although it is certainly not periodic. I would qualify it of "pseudo-periodic" with a stochastically distributed period, and a "random amplitude" at each oscillation. Here is what it looks like (partial graph, the data goes on for longer):

Now, while this is not a periodic series, oscillations between extrema with a fairly regular period can be seen at a glance. I wanted to analyze those oscillations more quantitatively and in particular get some information on the fundamental period/frequency. However, I am struggling to find suitable tools for the study of such a "non-periodic, oscillating time series". What would you recommend using, in particular to get pertinent information on the "fundamental frequency" of the oscillations that can be seen by the naked eye on the graph?
I have attempted to use a DFT to extract information in the frequency spectrum, but I get very muddy results, with a fairly broad range of frequency and no notable peak.

While this probably makes sense due to the non-periodic nature of the series that can only be obtained with broad mix of frequencies, this does not reflect very well the fact that there is a discernable "main oscillating" pattern with a reasonably peaked frequency. So DFT is doing its job alright, but is not providing me the information that is relevant for me. ACF did not give me much more exploitable information.
To illustrate, I manually extracted the period that I am talking about. To do so, I calculated the differential of the time series and extracted all the timestamps where it reaches zero (extremum in the time series). By differentiating the resulting array, I get a series of half-periods. A little more data handling can easily turn it into an array of periods. Here is the distribution of periods that I obtain throughout the whole time series:

I get a reasonably wide stochastic distribution with an identifiable peak around 0.4+/-0.15ps, which does fall within the frequency range of the FFT. This helps put some number on my graphical intuition, and can serve as a rough estimation of the frequency, but I suppose that there must be better and more rigorous tools to study such an oscillating pattern. Could you provide some guidance?
Here is a link to a csv text file containing the data. Time in ps in the first column, data in the second (normalized distance in Angstroms centered around 0):
https://filebin.net/8tqm97m0eiu3llc3

The tools that I am used to for analyzing periodic content require a much more regular waveform than what you are showing. To my eyes, your waveform may contain "true" periodicity of some kind. Or it might just be a lowpass filtered time series that appears to have some periodic component to our eyes?
Perhaps lowpass filtering + zero crossing would be a convenient way to get some notion of periodicity. Especially if you have a lot longer vector to work on.
What happens if you try to "whiten" the signal via e.g. LPC?

Can you upload any data for us to try out ideas with?

@Baddioes Sure thing, but I'm not sure what would be the most convenient way to do that. Do I just copy-paste a text file with the data in the question? There is 5000 data points total

@KnutInge I am unsure that there is a "true" periodicity in here, at least I am certain that this data set contains some true stochastic perturbation, since it comes from a molecular dynamics simulation. However, there is still a discernable period for oscillations and I was wondering if there is a set of tools dedicated to analyzing such a time series. I will need some time to research the suggestions you are making because I am not sure what either zero crossing or LPC means, but I will look into it!

@Baddioes I added a link to csv data file

@KnutInge so, zero crossing is essentially what I was doing, albeit with the derivative of the time series (tracking the extrema instead of the zeros, which seems more accurate in our case since the random amplitude does not always cross the zero at each oscillation). I don't think that a lowpass filter would help much since the manually extracted period of interest corresponds to the high end of the frequency spectrum of the FFT. As to the LPC, it seems much more involved but also designed for a wildly different type of data; my dataset is very remote from a speech waveform.

At this point I'm not really getting anything useful out of any parametric spectral estimators. Are you sure your period calculation from the time series data is correct?

Do you have a mathematical model of the system that's generating this?  If it's chaotic, or if it's a resonator being fed with lots of noise then trying to analyze it in terms of the frequency domain may not be of much use.

@Baddioes the calculation of the period distribution is pretty straightforward, but a basic mistake is never impossible! However, as Hilmar suggested, I actually obtained the same distribution for low-filtered white noise, suggesting that what I thought to be a "pseudo-period", is actually the "natural distribution of oscillations" in a purely random process limited to lower frequencies. The manually obtained peak in period distribution approximately corresponds to the cutoff frequency. Makes sense: highest present frequency governs the local extrema. Thank you for your contribution tho!

I think you are trying to see more than there really is. To me this looks like low pass filtered noise. I created white Gaussian distributed noise and filtered it with a 3rd order Butterworth at 2.8Hz and to me it looks very similar to your original data in both the time and frequency domain. At least I don't see any significant differences.
Frequency domain

Time domain


thank you for your insight! I think you are indeed correct. I reproduced your approach and on top of the similarity in both time and frequency domains, I also applied the "manual frequency extraction" strategy presented in the question by tracking the extrema. I obtain a very similar period distribution for my data as for low-filtered white noise. The underlying process therefore probably doesn't have a well defined period of oascillation, but is just purely random, with a limit on the frequencies involved (determined in my case by a Maxwell-Boltzmann energy distribution). Thanks!
